# Delete the tag "present"

Tags: support, tags

The tag is not used for any questions; it should be deleted. If we are going to use the tag *present-tense*, then *present* should be a synonymous of *present-tense*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a tag is no longer used, it is automatically deleted. This doesn't happen immediately. There are periodic cleanup operations that will eventually eliminate unused tags.

Comment: @Robert Cartaino: what is the approximate time between automatic cleanups? Is it on the order of hours, days, months, or years? Ref: *[The ghost of “meanning”](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/1448/the-ghost-of-meanning/1449#1449)*.

Comment: @Peter Mortensen: I believe the cleanup script runs once per day during off peak hours.

Comment: @Robert Cartaino: To clarify: according to waiwai933 it [doesn't apply for tag synonyms](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/1448/the-ghost-of-meanning/1449#1449) which aren't deleted automatically.