# The ghost of "meanning"

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

The *[tag synonyms for meaning](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/meaning/synonyms)* include *meanning* (extra `n`). Should *meanning* be removed from the list?

The tag itself was only used once and was deleted, I believe: *[Tag deletion request: [meanning]](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/743/tag-deletion-request-meanning)*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have deleted [meanning](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meanning) from the list of synonyms for [meaning](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning).

Answer (score 3):

Unused tags go away automatically after a while. See [Delete the tag "present"](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236/delete-the-tag-present)

Comment: What is the period between automatic cleanups? Tag "meanning" was apparently deleted more than 4 month ago.

Comment: @Peter The delay is (at most) one day, but doesn't apply for tag synonyms, which aren't deleted automatically.